# How do I stop townies running into a battle to collect gel/bones etc?

Tags: towns

I'm playing [towns](http://townsgame.com/) and have got a nice little town sorted out. Each time I've mined down a few layers I uncover a sprawling dungeon, which my heros dutifully explore, killing enemies as they go.

The problem is that once the first enemy is killed the townies decide to collect the loot and bring it back. Because they start this so soon there's often more enemies around making the collection run pretty dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you have raw material barrels or stockpiles lying around. When these barrels and stockpiles have space, your townies will search for items to fill these spaces. If bones and gels are not disabled, then your townies will mindlessly kill themselves for these materials so you can make colored hats.

To prevent this, right-click on your raw material barrels/stockpiles and disable bones and gels.

Comment: "suicide themselves for these materials so you can make **colored hats**", hmm that's a tough call. :D Is there any way without having to go through my (numerous) barrels?

Comment: To my knowledge, unfortunately no.